# @selector to a function in a separate class

Tags: iphone

If I have a function that is defined in class Foo, and my class Bar has a reference to class Foo, can I use the @selector to call that function?  Something like

```
@selector([Foo someFunctionInFoo:])
```

I have only used the @selector to call functions in the same class.  I tried doing something similar to the above code, but it didn't work and I wasn't sure if it was even possible.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@selector` doesn't store any calls information, just the selector.

```
[Foo performSelector:@selector(someFunctionInFoo:) withObject:nil];
```

You can also do:

```
Class class = SomeClass;
id obj = [class someObject];
SEL sel = @selector(someFunction);
[class performSelector:sel];
[obj performSelector:sel];
```

As long as both implement `someFunction`.

To specify which target is used by buttons etc you set the target and the action as two properties, e.g.:

```
[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Filter"
                                 style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                target:foo // The object to send the message to
                                action:@selector(someFunctionInFoo:)]; // The message to send
```

Comment: How would I tie this a selector when I create a UIBarButonItem though?  Like     self.ParentController.FilterButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Filter" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(FilterButtonPressed:)];

Comment: The 'target' parameter specifies which object to send the message to and the 'action' parameter specifies which selector to use. That's all the information you need to send the message wherever you want.

Comment: You replace `self` with `Foo`. That method is basically doing `[target performSelector:action]` when the bar button is pressed. I've updated my answer to include this...